# Should I try multiple different seed values when using a ROC curve to choose variables?

Tags: data-science, logistic-regression, curve, roc, random-seed

Say I have two subsets of variables, set A and set B. Set A is producing a much better ROC curve than set B, however, I have just realised that the ROC curve changes when using a different seed. Will set A always produce a better ROC curve than set B or should I be producing multiple ROC curves for each set using different seed values to compare the subsets of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases difference between seeds is **neglectable**. If you need to compare **how well** an algorithm is doing on different sets of data you surely need to use the **same seed**.